# I have a curl snippet that works, however I'm getting a 400 error with Guzzle, why?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong here?  Curl works but Guzzle (v6.3) gets a 400 error.

The Curl was generated by Postman:

Curl:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://unnamed-website.com/api2/v2/charges?chargeId=273628584&paymentGate=inovio",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "app-token: toktoktoktoktotkoktoktokt",
            "Content-type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Basic MDFkNWJiMTllYTdlZjVjODYzYTVjYjI3ZjUzNWY4NmM6YzFhMzRlNWJkZGYyMzljZTFmZDcwZjNiZDk0Y2Q4ZjA="
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Output:

Guzzle:

```
$guzzle = new Client();
$request = $guzzle->get("https://unnamed-website.com/api2/v2/charges?chargeId=273628584&paymentGate=inovio",
[
    'headers' => [
        "app-token" => "toktoktoktoktotkoktoktokt",
        "Content-type" => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Basic MDFkNWJiMTllYTdlZjVjODYzYTVjYjI3ZjUzNWY4NmM6YzFhMzRlNWJkZGYyMzljZTFmZDcwZjNiZDk0Y2Q4ZjA="
    ]
]);
$response = $request->send();
```

Output:

```
   Client error response
   [status code] 400
   [reason phrase] Bad Request
```

I've even tried adding thing like this:

```
    $request = $guzzle->get("https://unnamed-website.com/api2/v2/charges?chargeId=273628584&paymentGate=inovio",
        [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                ],
            'headers' => [
                "app-token" => "toktoktoktoktotkoktoktokt",
                "Content-type" => "application/json",
                "Authorization" => "Basic MDFkNWJiMTllYTdlZjVjODYzYTVjYjI3ZjUzNWY4NmM6YzFhMzRlNWJkZGYyMzljZTFmZDcwZjNiZDk0Y2Q4ZjA="
            ]
            ]);
```

Comment: You can try add a `['debug' => true]` to the options to see what's going on.

Comment: no change in output

Comment: Of course it won't change, but you can get the raw request: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug

Comment: How do these requests look on the server side?

Comment: This `$request = $guzzle->get` should already contain a response, whenever you are using shortcuts get/post etc. it's being sent out immediately. You call `$request->send()` on a response object for some reason.

Comment: @arma yes I got an exception for that as soon as I used the correct vendor package :)

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle can be call as follows:

```
<?php
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET',"https://unnamed-website.com/api2/v2/charges?chargeId=273628584&paymentGate=inovio",[
        'headers' => [
            "app-token" => "toktoktoktoktotkoktoktokt",
            "Content-type" => "application/json",
            "Authorization" => "Basic MDFkNWJiMTllYTdlZjVjODYzYTVjYjI3ZjUzNWY4NmM6YzFhMzRlNWJkZGYyMzljZTFmZDcwZjNiZDk0Y2Q4ZjA="
        ]
    ]);
    $response = $request->send();
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My fellow developers dug into this when I posted it on slack and they found the problem.  I was using  `use Guzzle\Http\Client;` when I should have been using `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` ... the former being was available due to a lot of unmanaged vendor packages laying around inside a giant proprietary framework.